# Finding two users with same pair group

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I have the following table which details actions of users and the action's parameters:

```
action_id(auto-increment) | user_id | action_name | action_attr1
```

I want to find which users performed the same actions exactly with same `action_attr1`. Meaning, I want to return all `user_ids` which have the same `group` of `<action_name, action_attr1>` pairs.

I tried relational-division but couldn't manage to get this working.
I also tried `outer join` and checking for `NULL` values but it wasn't correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually included the query you tried which did not work.

Comment: And an RDBMS would be nice.  And some test data.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings:

1. I have some serious doubts about the performance of this method at scale
2. I wrote this in SQL Server 2012. I don't know what RDBMS you are using.
3. I wrote this using ints for every datatype out of convenience since you didn't say.

That being said this will give you the right answer and might be a good starting point.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
( action_id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), 
    user_id int,
    action_name int, 
    action_attr1 int);

INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),
                        (2,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),
                        (3,1,1),(3,2,2),(3,3,3),
                        (4,1,1),(4,2,2),
                        (5,1,1),(5,2,2),(5,3,3),(5,4,4),
                        (6,1,1),(6,2,2);
GO

WITH PairValList AS (
    SELECT T1.user_id,
            (SELECT '('+CAST(action_name AS varchar(20)) + ',' + 
                            CAST(action_attr1 AS varchar(20)) + '), '
                    FROM #test T0
                    WHERE T0.user_id = T1.user_id
                    ORDER BY action_name, action_attr1 
                    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
                AS PairVals
    FROM #test T1
    GROUP BY T1.user_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(user_id AS varchar(20))
        FROM PairValList P0
        WHERE P0.PairVals = P1.PairVals
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
        , 1, 2, '') AS UserList
FROM PairValList P1;
GO
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code. This should give you the different users grouped by their pairs action_name and action_attr1.

```
select 
    action_name,
    action_attr1,
    user_id 
from myTable 
where 
    (action_name,action_attr1) in 
    (
        select distinct action_name, action_attr1 from myTable
    )
;
```